# RegEx with the symbol of //

Tags: php, regex

Here's the problem:

```
int x;
int y;

//cin >>x;
cin >>y;
```

PHP code:

```
<?php

if (preg_match_all("/\\x2F\s?cin\s?>>/", $line, $match)){
    if (preg_match_all("/\bcin\s?>>\s?\b/i", $line, $match)){
print " Correct";
}
else
print "cin,not found";
}
else
print "//cin,not found";

?>
```

How to make it works for example:

it will straight jump into `cin>> y` instead of `//cin>>x` by using RegEx.

The main idea of this is that, i am doing a web-based c++ compiler program, whenever student key in cin, then it will jump out a prompt box to let user to key in their value, but then if student type the code with //cin, my program still will jump the prompt box, i want it using RegEx to detect that if detected // then it wont run the specific line of the code.

Comment: Show the relevant part of your program.

Comment: what if they have `//[space][space]cin`? Still a comment, but your regex would treat it as executable code... Instead of looking for specific lines, you should exclude ALL comments as the very first thing you do. presumably you're doing this in a loop - before the loop starts, strip out lines with comments so you don't waste time figuring out what's on the line, since a commented line of code is irrelevant for execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex in PHP:

```
if (preg_match_all('~/{2}\s*cin\s*>>(*SKIP)(*F)|\s*\bcin\s*>>~', $line))
   print "uncommented cin found";
else
   print "uncommented cin not found";
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cT0hE2/1)

- `~` is using an alternate regex delimiter
- `/{2}\s*cin\s*>>` is finding instances of `cin` with comments in front of them
- `(*SKIP)(*F)` is skipping those commented matches of `cin`
- `|` is regex alternation
- `\s*\bcin\s*>>` is finding instances of all **uncommented** `cin`

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't match `//cin >>x` because your expression is `/\x2F\s?cin\s?>>/`. It starts with a single `/` encoded in hex (why?) followed by one or zero spaces and so on.

Why everybody uses forward slash (`/`) as regex delimiter, encloses the regex in quotes (`"`) then uses tons of backslashes for escaping? PHP functions that work with regex are flexible, they [accept a lot of characters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) as regex delimiter.

The regex can be written like this: `'#//\s?cin\s?>>#'`. It is more readable now.

Answer (score 0):

See the [demo here](https://regex101.com/r/dK6aS6/2)

I may have not think of all the cases

The regex is `^(?<!\/\/) *cin`

In details:

1. `^` is start of line
2. `(?<!\/\/)` is a negative lookbehind
3. `*` is 0 or more spaces
4. `cin` is litteraly cin

The negative lookbehind ensure it's impossible to match `//` before `cin` (with or without space before it)